# Cordova, iOS and iframe won't load content unless I allow-access href="*"

Tags: ios, cordova, iframe

I have a web app, which has an embedded map field, which is implemented using an iframe to https://maps.google.com/...

I am porting our app (which runs as a home screen icon currently) to Cordova on iOS, so adding a Cordova wrapper.  We already run the app via Cordova on Android.

I have a `div`, with a child element

`<iframe src="https://maps.google.com/?iwloc=&output=embed&q=something"></iframe>`

Initially, when the Cordova project was concerned only with Android, I had in `config.xml`

```
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="file://*" />
<access origin="http://*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*" />
```

However, this does not work.  The `iframe` with the map url doesn't even attempt to load, and there is no indication why.

So I started reading up and playing around with these settings, and on iOS basically, all they do is map to `NSAppTransportSecurity` settings in `Info.plist`.

Turns out that `<allow-navigation href="http://*" />` is ignored completely, only allow-navigation that specify domains or just * are supported, so I tried the more specific domain based ones, such as

`<allow-navigation href="http://maps.google.com/*" />`

Which does create a domain entry for `maps.google.com` and sets `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` to `true` but still the iframe won't load.

The ONLY thing I can find that allows the iframe to load the maps URL is by adding

`<allow-navigation href="*"/>`

Which essentially sets `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `true` which basically turns TLS off, and will trigger an app review and require justification.

SideNote: `<access origin="*"/>` also sets `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `true` but alone prevents the initial URL from loading inside the webview (it loads externally).

I am at a bit of a loss as to what combination of config.xml or `NSAppTransportSecurity` settings I need to get this working without just allowing everything and the app review issues that will undoubtedly trigger.

Note: These requests don't trigger a CSP warning, I don't think the webview is even getting that far, and if I set allow-navigation to * it works, which would suggest CSP is fine.

When it fails, all I get in web debugger for that request is 'an error occurred trying to load the resource', and nothing in XCode console.

Comment: Hi Austin. Did you find a solution to this problem? I find myself in almost exactly the same position; i want to include an iframe with https://calendar.google.com content in my IOS app.

Comment: It seems I did, but I don't know how I did it. Looking back at my logs, I gave up on  problem and moved onto other stuff. Testing it now on an iPhone 10, map embedded in an iframe in a webview is working. I am using <allow-navigation href="*" /> in config.xml

Comment: One thing I did do is rebuild my project from scratch. Originally I had used cordova to create the project and was maintaining (and customising) that. I later scrapped that approach and did all customisation via plugins, so the project is entirely generate from scratch each build. It's vaguely possible something had crept into the original project that was fouling things up, but what I can't imagine.

Comment: I notice that you have an "https" URL in your iframe, but in allow-navigation you only specify "http"... However I think you are right about allow-navigation only supporting "*" or complete URLs; that is my experience, too. Also, you mention CSP but did you include a CSP meta header in the HTML at all?

Answer (score 9):

After struggling with the same problem, I found a configuration that worked for me!

I want my app to include Google Calendar in an iframe, which means I need to specify for Cordova that the URL of Google Calendar should be handled within the app's webview.

Having `<allow-navigation href="*" />` makes it work, but it has the side effect that all links the user clicks will be handled inside the web view as well (my app has functionality for giving the user a feed of news, and sometimes there are links in the text for the user to click). Having arbitrary web pages inside my app's fullscreen web view rendered no way for the user to navigate back to my app. On  Android there is always a "back button", but on iOS there is none, forcing the user to quit the application.

My solution was two-fold: specify URLs in allow-navigation and setup a CSP that will allow content and scripts:

In `config.xml`:

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="https://calendar.google.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://apis.google.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://clients6.google.com/*" />
```

On iOS it was not enough to have `calendar.google.com`; I had to find all the domains that was accessed by the iframe, hence the need for the three URLs above. I used the network log in Chrome's inspect tool to find these domains.
For Android this was not necessary.

I could have set `<allow-navigation href="https://*.google.com/* />`, but that would have opened up too broadly for my needs (e.g. links to "www.google.com" would have been handled in webview instead of external browser).

In `index.html`:

```
<head>
...
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
          content="default-src * 'self' data: gap: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
          style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' gap:;
          script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' gap:;">
...
```

Note - the CSP above is probably allowing way too much. But this is a starting point and then you can narrow the access according to your app's needs.

Now the app renders the `iframe` with Google Calender URL correctly on both iOS and Android, and lets other links invoke the device's browser, i.e. outside the app.

Comment: CSP + white list configs works for me, with IFrame window in IOS with Cordova. Thanks a lot

Comment: this works for me and also I have to add  frame-src * at the end of the meta tag like this. Thanks a lot!!

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src * 'self' data: gap: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
      style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' gap:;
      script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' gap:; frame-src *;">